# Why is my Spring Security Hashed Password not Authenticating?

Tags: java, spring, hash

If I remove the hashed passwords it authenticates like a charm, but when I save the passwords with the hashing and then set it to Spring for comparison it simply just doesn't work, it doesn't authenticate.

Here is my Hashpassword code:

```
@Autowired
protected void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(springUserService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(springUserService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

As expected the Spring Encrypter works fine, so It's just a matter of my configuration I guess. Here is the test:

```
public class TestBCrypt {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    //String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode("123");
    //System.out.println(encodedPassword);
    System.out.println(passwordEncoder.matches("123","$2a$10$KZkrMlK2dnyKfKa3xvRSMukQzmul.DUgOvdv7GFezqGFmoBeFDkt.")); // prints true
}
```

}

Comment: could you post also your login controller?

Comment: You either set the `userDetailsService` or the `authenticationProvider` not both.